# Sync local git branch with remote git branch that deleted a specific commit

Tags: git

I share a remote git repository. A user actually removed a specific commit that they did not want in the git history (the commit is not the latest commit). Perhaps they did something like this:

```
git reset --hard <sha1-commit-id>
git push origin HEAD --force
```

I am not 100 percent if these are the commands they used. All I know is the commit is no longer in the remote repository. I have the commit in my local git repository though. And it is not HEAD (the latest commit). It is like 10 commits back in git log output:

```
git log
...
commit a5df5
Author:
Date:
This is the commit that I have locally but no longer in remote
```

Now whenever I do a git push, it reappears back in the remote repository. How can I ensure this commit no longer is pushed to the remote repository?

I am thinking to do this:

```
git fetch origin latest_stuff
git reset --hard origin/latest_stuff
```

Will this ensure that specific git commit is gone from my local machine?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be extremely careful to make other people aware of the situation so that things like this don't happen.

So... how can it be fixed? It can be corrected on your side, actually. So... say the commit that you want to be removed has ID xxxxxxxx, then:

```
git checkout xxxxxxxx~1 # we go back one commit from the one we want to discard from history
git cherry-pick xxxxxxxx..the-branch # replay the history of the branch _after_ the revision you want to delete
git branch -f the-branch # set pointer of branch to new location
git push origin -f the-branch
```

That way the revision has been removed from history... it has implications if there are yet more developers working on the project (because they would have the revision you want to delete on their branches). Make sure that all developers are aware and rebase their work if needed before trying to push on the "new" clean branch.

Comment: Just to be clear, in git cherry-pick xxxxxxxx..the-branch, the two dots refer to the specific git commit, so it would be like this? git cherry-pick a5df5 latest_stuff

Comment: I am not sure this answers the question. The git commit was already removed from the remote branch. My question is about how to rebase my work so I do not send that commit back into remote repository.

Comment: The dots are there, that's how you tell git that it's a range of revisions for cherry-pick.... And I gave my recipe based on what you said about pushing and seeing the revision on the remote.

Comment: I just want to make clear to you that the commit is already removed from remote from someone else. It is still in my git log of my local git repository.

Comment: The recipe without the push will clean up whatever branch, by the way.

Comment: Now what do I do? it says: HEAD detached from 3d6de7e5
You are currently cherry-picking commit a0acf540.

Comment: Is there a conflict? It sounds like it is. If that is the case, then take care of it, add all files to index and then _do not commit_. Run `git cherry-pick --continue`.

Comment: This is not working at all. When I did a git push. It says everything is up to date.

Comment: On your local branch, the revision you wanted to delete is gone?

Comment: Actually, the question should be: did you move the local branch pointer to the newly rewritten branch out that came out of the cherry-pick?

Comment: And what was wrong with using git revert on that commit? Why didn't you recommend the git revert solution?

Comment: Because I see no point in keeping a revision that is plain wrong in the history of a branch if I have the means to get rid of it so I would remove it from the history of the branch, as your friend did. This involves additional work if other people are already working with that branch, as you are doing right now. But once you get the concepts right, you will see that it actually is rather simple to solve.

Comment: Plus, you were actually asking to get your branch to have that revision removed (just like I would do) so why would I think of revert then? :-)

Comment: You're right. I did not want to revert. But I cannot get your technique to work at all.

Comment: Let's chat to see if I can get you through it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180969/discussion-between-eftshift0-and-donato).